# jQuery tooltip add line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

So, I want to take the content of a div in which I have several `<br/>`, and then pass it as a title attribute using jQuery tooltip widget. I want the lines to appear one beneath the other inside the tooltip. thx. the code so far is:

**CSS**

```css
.Lines {
    width: 125px;
    height:20px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip();

    $(".Lines").hover(function () {
        IaTxt = $(this).html()

        $(this).prop('title', IaTxt)

    })
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="Lines">
    First line.
    <br/>Second line.
    <br/>Third line!
    <br/>Fourth line?
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the 'content' option of the tooltip widget. See also:

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

Short example:

```
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      content: function() {
        return 'foo'
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: could you give a practical example, that would achieve my goal? thx

Comment: The string 'foo' can in your case be replaced by Iatext

Answer (score 67):

There's a pure CSS solution. Use \n for newlines, and add this CSS style:

```
.ui-tooltip {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

You can also use pre or pre-wrap instead of pre-line, if you want to preserve whitespace.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: By far the easiest solution on this page.

Comment: Easiest solution for me as well. My text already contained \n so I only needed the CSS. Thanks!

Comment: The class selector was different for my version of Jquery Tooltip:

`
.tooltip-inner {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
`

But same principle!

Answer (score 19):

just use the entity `&#10;` for a linebreak in a title attribute.

Comment: how specifically would I implement that in my code? i set the title attribute via jQuery

Comment: add the text, where you want the line break. or replace with the <br/> tag

Comment: I don't know if you understood my initial question. I want to take the content of the div [see example div] and display it as a title with jQuery tooltip plugin. in that div i already have `<br/>` and I want the line breaks to appear in the tooltip where the `<br/>` are.

Comment: thats only i told. u replace the <br/> with &#10; `yourVariable.replace("<br/>","&#10;");`

Comment: You have to use this together with this:

.ui-tooltip {
    white-space: pre-line;
}

Answer (score 15):

This is my trick to do it with latest jquery / jqueryui (assuming all of the items you want to have tooltips have class 'jqtooltip', they have title tags, and the title has a pipe character for a line separator:

```
$('.jqtooltip').tooltip({ 
  content: function(callback) { 
     callback($(this).prop('title').replace('|', '<br />')); 
  }
});
```

Comment: this only replaces the first '|'.

Answer (score 7):

You could type your HTML directly into the Title attribute and then simply call the following:

```
$(document).tooltip({
  content: function (callback) {
     callback($(this).prop('title'));
  }
});
```

This way your HTML is rendered instead of escaped and literally written.

Comment: This is THE answer. Period. Please upvote in order to move this answer on the top.

Comment: the tooltip will not hide after hover.

Answer (score 3):

better use this:

```
$(document).tooltip({
   content: function () {
     return $( this ).prop( 'title' ).replace( '|', '<br />' );
   }
});
```

with `function(callback)` i had an issue with tooltips which wasn't close

Comment: Great if you have 1 newline. For multiples be sure to use global option. `.replace( /\|/g, '<br />' );`

Comment: Please look into this page the JDandChips answer, the use of custom characters is unnecessary. You can use html in the title attribute simply changing the function in :

return $( this ).prop( 'title');

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```
        $("[title]").each(function(){
            $(this).tooltip({ content: $(this).attr("title")});
        });
```

It means all elements with a title attribute is going to use the jquery tooltip and the tooltip content will use the value of the title attribute.
The content allows html.

Comment: Also I had to replace /n with <br/> in my text before setting the title attribute with it. But now I found a better solution, I wrap it with <pre> tag and it keeps line breaks and tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I went with a modified version of ScottRFrost's answer. The problem with his example is that .replace only replaces the first instance of the character in the string. Here is a modified version that will use the regex's /g (global) to modify all instances of the character in the entire string.

```
$('.jqtooltip').tooltip({ 
   content: function (callback) {
      callback($(this).prop('title').replace(new RegExp("\\|", "g"), '<br />'));
   }
});
```

Comment: You can also use a regex pattern like : `.replace(/\|/g, '<br />')`.