# jQuery not working with tooltip new line character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string of an html element, something like

```
"<div title=\"123 &#13; 123\">test</div>"
```

When I insert this into the DOM and view this on the page, I see like

```
123
123
```

as a tooltip. However when I try to change its title value using jquery:

```
element.prop("title", "456 &#13; 456");
```

I see like

```
456 &#13; 456
```

as the tooltip. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: you can use `<br\>` in the title attribute.

Comment: That has the same effect as `&#13;`. i.e. it literally shows `<br\>` in the title when I change it using jquery.

Comment: so you're saying you've tried it and it doesn't work? you may also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599562/jquery-tooltip-add-line-break

Comment: I think that is using the jquery widgit tooltip. I am talking about the standard browser tooltip.

Comment: oh I'm sorry the jquery tag (and title) threw me. thought you were using jquery tooltips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your first example, `&#13;`  is parsed into the DOM by the browser, that correctly understands the entity.

in the second example, it does not get parsed by the browser, but injected by javascript directly into the DOM. So you need to use the appropiate javascript coding.

```
.prop('title',"456 \r 456");
```

try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pEbt2/5/

Answer (score 1):

use `.prop("title", "456 \n 456");`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is:

```
.prop( 'title', ['456',String.fromCharCode(13),'456'].join(' ') );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to handle HTML special characters in tooltips such as `&#13;` or `&#8364;` (Euro symbol), you can create an empty, unseen div element, set it with your html then convert it to text using:

```
element.prop("title", $('<div/>').html('456 &#13; 456').text());
```